# Text cursor disappears when swaping fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

Fragment A has EditText view. This view has focus. I replace fragment A with fragment B and then replace back B with A. The result is that text cursor in EditText view disappear. Though the focus is on the view. Tapping on the view doesn't result in cursor appearence. Cursor appears only when I start typing letters in the view or when I tap on another EditText view. How to fix it?

Comment: In XML of fragment A use the tag `<requestFocus/>` inside EditText `<EditText ...><requestFocus/></EditText>` .

Comment: I cache fragment views, do not recreate them in Fragment's onCreateView (create once for the first time).

Comment: Then use method requestFocus() for EditText inside the method `onResume()` or `onStart()`

Comment: Vladimir, there are several EditText views in fragment A that shows such a behaviour. To what one should I add <requestFocus/>? :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by caching fragments as well.